# CSS affect only elements that are inside a container?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a CSS file that in short contains blocks like this:

```
%container .grass {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    height:3%;
    background-color:#4CAF50;
    width:105%;
    margin-left:-10px;
}
```

Where %container is the container where all elements with class .grass should be affected, %container is always an id say #container or #appcontent

But I think I'm wrong somewhere because it's not working, and it may be something really simple too, so where is it?

I have more content such as:

```
%container .subcontainer:not(.ui-draggable-dragging) {
    cursor:grab;
}
%container .numbercontainer > .number, %container .signcontainer > .sign {
    display:block;
}
```

Okay here is the preprocessor, I'm absolutely sure it generates the content properly because I checked its output and the result given, but for some reason it doesn't work.

```
App.prototype.getMainCSS = function(url) {
    console.log("GET: " + url);
    if (App.dependenciesLoaded.indexOf(url) === -1) {
        $.get(url,(function(data){
            var cssfile = document.createElement("link")
            cssfile.rel = "stylesheet";
            cssfile.type = "text/css";
            cssfile.innerHTML = data.replace(/%container/g,"#" + this.element.id);
            App.dependenciesLoaded.push(url);
            document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(cssfile);
        }).bind(this));
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming you don't really have the %container thing in your CSS right and its just for example purposes here?  Also, can you create a fiddle showing what you mean?

Comment: % ...Do you mean '#' for id's or '.' for class ..  `#container` or `.container`

Comment: assuming you use # instead of %, the css is correct. You'll have to show also the related html

Comment: Those look more like [SASS placeholders](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#placeholder_selectors_) or some other pre-processing element. `%...` has no meaning in a CSS selector.

Comment: [link](http://pastie.org/9975531) there is the total file for an example situation.

Comment: %container is not in the css file after it's parsed, it's replaced by an id.

Comment: The css is also loaded dinamically

Comment: @Edward you might want to mention or tag your CSS processor, so that we can know exactly what we are _fiddling_ (hint) about.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ctjj9cd0/ well it works there...

Comment: @Edward This one better represents what you want to achieve IMO: http://jsfiddle.net/ctjj9cd0/1/

Comment: @JanosWeisz yes exactly, now I think it's not a css problem but may be related to processing the data in javascript.

Comment: It's definetly not a CSS problem, I checked the CSS generated, saved it, created a test case and it works, with dynamic generation it doesn't... I'm sorry guys.

Answer (score 0):

This solves it.

```
App.prototype.getMainCSS = function(url) {
    console.log("GET: " + url);
    if (App.dependenciesLoaded.indexOf(url) === -1) {
        $.get(url,(function(data){
            var cssfile = document.createElement("style") //not link
            //cssfile.rel = "stylesheet"; useless line
            cssfile.type = "text/css";
            cssfile.innerHTML = data.replace(/%container/g,"#" + this.element.id);
            App.dependenciesLoaded.push(url);
            document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(cssfile);
        }).bind(this));
    }
}
```